# How can I implement BGP on ryu?

Tags: python, ryu, bgp

I need to connect two Autonomous Systems by using the BGP running on Ryu controller. I've been trying to implement different codes I found, but I don't know how to do it properly.  Please provide any method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the BGP implementation that comes with Ryu?  You can find it in the directory (relative to the ryu home directory:

```
./ryu/services/protocols/bgp
```

I haven't played with this yet but looking through the source it seems like a reasonably complete application.   Let me know if this meets your needs.

Comment: I can't find how to implement that, because there are many files on the folder you mention, but I don't know how can I run them. I'll appreciate if you can tell me any ideas.